# How do I create another controller action to create an object in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, action

I have a model called Contact_Email.  When an Email template is sent through ActionMailer to a specific Contact, as part of the Create action it sends it through upon .save.

However, I want to create a "skip" action which also creates a Contact_Email, but does NOT send an ActionMailer and allows me to set the status differently.

I want to create a separate action because I want to make this respond to a remote_for_tag so that I can just have an ajax button indicate it has been "skipped":

Here's what I tried, but while it creates a Contact_Email, I end up getting an error when I want to go back and view all the Contacts again.

```
  def skip
    @contact_email = ContactEmail.new
    @contact_email.contact_id = params[:contact_id]
    @contact_email.email_id = params[:email_id]

    @contact_email.status = "skipped"

    if @contact_email.save
      flash[:notice] = "skipped email"
      redirect_to contact_emails_url
    end
  end
```

Comment: What is the error? The code you show seems fine.

Comment: When I try to show a list of all the Emails that are "overdue", I get an "expect 1 attribute)" or something error.  It gets fixed when i edit the newly created contact_email and save, which creates a created_date and sent_date.  Then the error goes away, but I don't use those dates...I guess i could just add it in the controller to see...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your code seems ok, just a few things.

- You have no else statement, what if your
  @contact_email is not saved?
- You should definately NOT assign all of the params separately. Use a form in the view for contact_email and 
  `@contact_email = ContactEmail.new(params[:contact_email])` in controller. Though having "skipped" assigned separately is ok
- Define you routes correctly. In this case
  `map.resources :contact_emails, :member => {:skip => :post}`
  And everything should be just fine

Comment: Ah I think this should be better (but the same) as this:   map.skip_email "contact_email/skip_email/:contact_id/:email_id",
            :controller => "contact_emails",
            :action => "skip"